# Are NFL season tickets valid on Panini trading cards?

Tags: american-football, nfl, collectibles

I am not from the US and I got some NFL trading cards by Panini from the set "contenders football 2021".

I think the season ticket on it is just fake.

But because there is a seat number I am not 100% sure.

Do the numbers have any meaning?

Maybe I get some discount when showing the card?

Is a season ticket for a whole season or just for one match?

(I know season 2021 is already over.)
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm not convinced that questions about trading cards are on-topic here, but I'll defer to the mods.

Comment: @F1Krazy I think it's both a sports and trading cards question?

Comment: Given the question is about it being an actual ticket, I guess it's close enough, though we certainly don't have much in the way of experts on cards.  In this case I think it's obvious enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, this is not a real ticket (nor does it have, as far as I can tell, any bearing on ticket pricing).  The numbers are the player's jersey number, their height, and their weight.  For example, Joe Burrow wears [#9, is 6'4", and 221 pounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Burrow).